# Date from date picker is not displaying in the update form where i use the patch value in angular,while other data is displaying

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

im using angular material date picker ,and using patch data to display the data in edit form, in other fields data are displaying but in the date field the patch data is not showing when update.From the server the date is coming like this 
createdAt: "2020-04-04T00:00:00.000+0000,Is it because of this date is not showing? if it is so how can we show the date in the form can anyone give the solution for this.

```
  <mat-form-field class="date" (click)="createAt.open()">
                  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="createAt" autocomplete="off" formControlName="createAt" placeholder="Date"
                    [value]="createAt" > 
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="createAt"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #createAt></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
```

```
  this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
   createAt: [new Date()],
})
```

Comment: Still didnt get any solution for this.can anyone help me how can we solve this issue

Comment: i got the solution for this    this.firstFormGroup.controls['createdAt'].setValue(new Date(data.createdAt));and also i removed the value in html since it is overidiing the value formcontrolname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer hope it will help someone

```
this.firstFormGroup.controls['createdAt'].setValue(data.createdAt);
```